# URI is not absolute?

Tags: java

I have a File

```
/user/guest/work/test/src/main/java/Test.java
```

And a [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)-Object:

```
File f = new File("/user/guest/work/test/src/main/java/Test.java");
```

I need this outputs

```
System.out.println(f);                   ->                       src/main/java/Test.java
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath()); -> /user/guest/work/test/src/main/java/Test.java
```

I tried:

```
File relativeTo = new File("/user/guest/work/test");
new File(relativeTo.toURI().relativize(f.toURI()));
```

but it is throwing a

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
   at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:416)
   at Test.<init>(Test.java:43)
```

How to get the required output?

Comment: I don't understand why you need `relativize`

Comment: I need the relative name to hide the username/project-folder in logging

Comment: The File constructor needs an absolute path. You can print the relativize value, but not construct a new file from it

Comment: Try `File relativeTo = new File("./user/guest/workspace/test");`

Comment: @cricket_007 Hm, only the File-constructor(URI uri) requires a absolute, we have constructors in File that allowes to use relative and absolute, even only relative parameters.

Comment: @MurilloGoulart Your suggestion creates a File pointing to `/user/tomcat/user/guest/workspace/test` what does not exists and is wrong from my point of view.

Comment: @Cricket_007 That is simply untrue. Consider `new File("x.tmp")`.

Comment: @EJP that's a different constructor than the one that's used in the question, so out of context, sure you are correct

Comment: @EJP just for editorial: the term "simply untrue" is only a little bit correct, the truth is never simple so a "untrue" is a little bit more correct. In example `file:///var/log/debug.log` might look like a absolute uri and it will be interpreted to the more qualified `file://localhost/var/log/debug.log` but only if localhost is pointing to `127.0.0.1` then the much more absolute uri is like `file://127.0.0.1/var/log/debug.log`. According to https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8089 the real local-absolute uri would be: `file:/var/log/debug.log`.

Comment: @cricket_007 It is not 'a different constructor than the *one* that's used in the question' [emphasis added]. There are *two* used in the question. Does your comment refer to`File(URI)`? You need to make yourself clear.

Comment: @PeterRader Just for editorial, the truth is often extremely simple, and 'a 'little bit more correct' is a pleonasm.

Comment: @EJP I am unable to edit my months old comment that perhaps would say "that File constructor". Anyways, I feel like I've made myself clear in the answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`relativize` returns a URI.

a `new File(URI uri)` takes...

> uri - **An absolute**, hierarchical URI

You can instead try using the String constructor.

```
new File(relativeTo.toURI().relativize(f.toURI()).toString());
```

---

You have access to that file other ways, however

For example, you can try going through the `java.nio.file.Path` API instead of `java.io.File`

Like

```
Path path = Paths.get("/", "user", "guest", "workspace", 
    "test", "src", "main", "java", "Test.java");
Path other = ...
Path relPath = other.relativize(path);

//    relPath.toString(); // print it
//    relPath.toFile();   // get a file
```

Comment: You can use `toRealPath` if you don't want the `..\ `

Comment: I know what you telling me, but I do not understand the way you gather this idea. Did you found external informations or did you create this informations by yourself?

Comment: I don't remember. It apparently was over a year ago

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, it wasnt helpfull but incredible informative. (Readers might want know, but it is ...)

Answer (score 4):

You can use path resolve to relativize file paths

```
  File f = new File("/user/guest/workspace/test/src/main/java/Test.java");
  File relativeTo = new File("/user/guest/workspace/test");
  System.out.println(new File(relativeTo.toPath().resolve(f.toPath()).toUri()));
```

Comment: This is a workaround to not use `getAbsolutePath`. I do not like to create a new File-instance for logging only.

Comment: `new File("/src/main/java...` picks up from the root directory, doesn't it?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, in every constructor.

Comment: @PeterRader: I have edited my answer, see if this works for you